# How to detect if an image in a html is fully loaded in WKWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm loading a local html with a < img> tag e.g. :

```
< img class="icon" src="data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAlgCWAAD/7gAOQWRvYmUAZAAAAAAA/...
```

However, how can I detect if the image is fully loaded? I'm using this to detect. However, it doesn't seem to work. Sometimes the image is loaded, sometimes it's not.

```
-(void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation{
    if (webView.isLoading) return;
    ..
    //proceed to load the second html
}
```

**Update:**

I've added a delay in the didFinishNavigation delegate and the image is loaded perfectly:

```
-(void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation{
if (webView.isLoading) return;


double delayInSeconds = 3.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    NSLog(@"Do some work");

});

}
```

However, this is an interim solution. Is there a better solution?

Comment: you can refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313253/how-to-check-if-wkwebview-finish-loading-in-objective-c

Comment: yes I'm already using webView:didFinishNavigation: to detect. However, does it trigger after the base64 image is loaded or before?

Answer (score 2):

My solution is using javascript code to check content's height of `webView`. If the height is bigger than or equal a number (it means that having something inside webView, it's the image), post a message to `webView` and use `WKScriptMessageHandler` to handle message in native code.

**Example**

Create javascript code. Check if content's height is bigger than 50, post message to check image is loaded.

```
NSString* source =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:
                  @"var sizeInterval = setInterval("
                   "function() {"
                   "var h = 0;"
                   "var children = document.body.children;"
                   "for (var c = 0; c < children.length; c++) {"
                   "h += children[c].offsetHeight;"
                   "}"
                   "if (h > 50) {"
                   "clearInterval(sizeInterval);"
                   "window.webkit.messageHandlers.%@.postMessage('loaded');"
                   "}"
                   "},"
                   "100);",
                  kContentLoadedMessage];

WKUserScript* script = [[WKUserScript alloc]
      initWithSource:source
       injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentStart
    forMainFrameOnly:YES];

WKUserContentController* contentController =
    [[WKUserContentController alloc] init];
[contentController addUserScript:script];
[contentController addScriptMessageHandler:self name:kContentLoadedMessage];

WKWebViewConfiguration* configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
configuration.userContentController = contentController;

YOUR_WK_WEB_VIEW =
    [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero configuration:configuration];
// Add webView to a view and load html
```

Using `WKScriptMessageHandler` to handle message.

```
- (void)userContentController:(WKUserContentController*)userContentController
      didReceiveScriptMessage:(WKScriptMessage*)message {
  if ([message.name isEqualToString:kContentLoadedMessage]) {
    NSLog(@"Image was loaded");
  }
}
```

You can check [my demo repo](https://github.com/trungducc/stackoverflow/tree/wkwebview-detect-image-loaded) for more understanding.

Comment: Hi @trungduc, it's a nice trick if the image frame is not loaded. In my case, the image frame is there (hence, the height of the webview is the same when the image is loaded and when it's not) just that the image is not loaded :(

Comment: Ok I got it. Can you show me the way you changed image? I think we just need to change javascript to be suitable with your problem.

Comment: I'm just using a simple image tag, the data source is in base64 format as shown in the question. < img class="icon" src="data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAlgCWAAD/7gAOQWRvYmUAZAAAAAAA/...>

Comment: So in case image isn't loaded, src will be empty. Is it right?

Comment: It's hard to replicate the issue. Are you able to test it using a very large data source? Theoretically the source will be empty when the image is not loaded.

Comment: If src is empty in case image isn't loaded, my solution will work. You should download repo to check first. Try to remove src in my html string and you will know it work or not.

Comment: Image is still missing after trying for a few times. Is it cause by WKWebview rendering issue?

Comment: I don't think it's `WKWebView` rendering issue. I think you should check the way you change image.

Comment: removing the base64 image and replace with a file. <img width="300px;" height="230px;" src="Logo.jpeg">. Not sure if this is what you meant...

Comment: `Image is still missing after trying for a few times`. Do you mean image doesn't appear or `didReceiveScriptMessage` didn't be called?